# Change class using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, class, attributes

I have a td with follwoing class named 'rgExpandCol' and want to change the class of input inside it. below is my html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="rgExpandCol">
    <input class="rgExpand" ...
    </td>
<tr>
```

and I have tried this jquery but I get $find is null:

```
$(this).closest('td').attr('rgExpand', 'rgCollapse');
```

EDIT :::

basically am using `radgrid` and expanding rows which are hidden using

`$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css('display', '');`

and $(this) is on my click event of grid as so

```
$("#<%=gv.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use removeClass() and addClass() to make the change.

```
$("#<%=gv.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input').addClass('rgExpand').removeClass('rgCollapse');
});
```

Assuming that the id used in the selector identifies the table.

Comment: the problem is i have loads of classes with rgExpand hence wanting to find the next td and input of it...

Comment: You need to show more of your markup and describe what you're trying to do more clearly. How do you arrive at $(this)?

Comment: basically am using radgrid and expanding rows which are hidden using $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css('display', ''); and $(this) is on my click event of grid as so $("#<%=gv.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {

Comment: Can you update your post rather than posting code in a comment? It'll make it easier for us to work with.

Comment: Why are you using :has(td)?

Comment: can i do input.rgExpand on find as right now it works but replaces all input items in there

Comment: Sure you can. What do you mean "replaces"? All we're doing is changing the class.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesnt work, how can i say if it is not input.myclass then remove class...my fault for saying replace as the class has image of its own so replaces my input class images

Comment: I fear that your explanation of the problem isn't clear and that is why wee're not able to give you something that will work as you want it to. If you want to say not input.myclass use .not('input.myclass')

Answer (score 2):

First you need to select the input, which can ben done with a single selector :

```
var my_input = $(this).find('input.rgExpand');
```

Then you can remove its current class and add the new one :

```
my_input
    .removeClass('rgExpand')
    .addClass('rgCollapse');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('td').find("input").removeClass("old").addClass("new")
```

Will apply the CSS for inputs inside the TD :)

Comment: this changes the td class, is there way to make it change the input class

Comment: @Sam1 updated.. note if u want to apply the CSS for a single input, use an ID in the find() function.. the updated code will apply it for all inputs in that TD

Comment: This won't work, as it doesn't necessarily find a `TD` with a class of `rgExpandCol`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr td.rgExpandCol input.rgExpand').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.rgExpandCol > input').removeClass("< existing class >").addClass("< new class >");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to target the td and change the class of the input inside it?

I'd do this:

`$('.rgExpandCol > input').removeClass('classtoremove').addClass('newclasstoadd');`