# Change Class in JQuery failed

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to change a Class of A div but it failed.

see code below :

```
$('form div').attr('form-group has-error', 'form-group');
```

Comment: you must be reading here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change class using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880496/change-class-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Vinay Prajapati :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is the attribute name, and the second parameter is the value. Your code isn't working because the element doesn't have a `form-group has-error` attribute.

If you want to select an element with the classes `form-group` and `has-error`, then use the selector `.form-group.has-error` and change the `class` attribute instead:

```
$('form div.form-group.has-error').attr('class', 'form-group');
```

If you're just trying to remove the `.has-error` class, you could also just use the `.removeClass()` method:

```
$('form div.form-group.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
```

Comment: Thanks Josh Crozier :)